# Почему в Java возможно создание двух MulticastSocket на одном порту?

Tags: java, сеть

Изучаю принципы работы Java Web Sockets. Не могу понять почему возможно создание двух MulticastSocket на одном порту без возникновения исключения например:

```
MulticastSocket socket = new MulticastSocket(4446);
MulticastSocket socket1 = new MulticastSocket(4446);
```

Хотя в случае обычного DatagramSocket:

```
DatagramSocket datagramSocket = new DatagramSocket(3333);
DatagramSocket datagramSocket1 = new DatagramSocket(3333);
```

выбрасывается исключение: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: Cannot bind, что логично.